# JSON response with dash in the key-name

Tags: java, json, jackson, response, netflix-feign

I am using feign for my rest-calls. Unfortunately one of the responses I get looks something like this:

```
{
    "customer-id" : "0123"
}
```

The JSON response automatically gets mapped to one of my POJO's. This response object can not have a property field with the name "customer-id", as the dash (-) is not allowed in the name of an identifier.

I tried the following:

```
public class LookUpAccountsResponse {
        @JsonProperty("customer-id")
        private String customerId;
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Where in the JSON specification does it say dashes aren't allowed?

Comment: What do you mean with a JSON specification? I know the JSON response has a - in its key ("customer-id"). The problem is to create a Java property field with a similar name (so it can be mapped).

Comment: There's a standard definition for valid JSON keys http://json.org... I'm not sure what the error is, but the answer below suggests that the dash isn't the issue, so can you try to create a [mcve] like they have?

Comment: Thank God, we have StackOverflow. It saves me always

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> com.google.gson.GsonDecoder

Not sure why `JsonProperty` is on your classpath, but see "field naming support" https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#json-field-naming-support

`@SerializedName` is the Gson annotation you'll want

Or switch entirely to using the `feign-jackson` dependency with a `JacksonDecoder`

Comment: Finally, this worked for me. Added `@SerializedName` on top of the property which was having 'hypen' in their names. It looked like    ` @JsonProperty("auth-key")  @SerializedName("auth-key")  private String authKey;`. I left the `@JsonProperty` annotation as it is as all other properties was having it.

Comment: That would mean you have both Jackson and Gson on your classpath, which really is unncessary

Comment: I refactored and removed `@JsonProperty("auth-key")` which was completely unnecessary.  WIll remove jackson from classpath if there is no other dependency in project. Meanwhile, after your comment, I revisited my module and added the following in my `application.yml` 1.  `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper= gson` and 2. 
`gson.field-naming-policy= LOWER_CASE_WITH_DASHES` as default strategy. Now, I didn't need to add `@SerializedName ("auth-key")` as the default strategy is taking care.

Answer (score 5):

It works fine.  Here is a minimal example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    SomeClass sc = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"property-with-dash\": 5}", SomeClass.class);

    System.out.println(sc.propertyWithDash);
  }

  public static class SomeClass {
    @JsonProperty("property-with-dash")
    private int propertyWithDash;
  }
```

This prints `5` as expected.  No complaints.

Comment: I am not using an ObjectMapper. I'm not sure what the Feign framework does to map the response to my response object.

Comment: Do you know what framework it is using?  Because that would determine how to configure this.  I assumed Jackson since you were using the `@JsonProperty` annotation.

Comment: @Robert Are you using the `GsonDecoder` or `JacksonDecoder`? If the latter, it does use ObjectMapper

Comment: I guess I've thrown everybody off with the JsonProperty annotation. I have now changed it to SerializedName and this does work.

Answer (score 0):

Using JsonObjects and JsonArrays will allow you to get keys and values as Strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use @JsonAlias.

It  defines one or more alternative names for a property to be accepted during deserialization i.e. setting JSON data to Java object.

@JsonAlias("customer-id")

private String customerId;