# How to deserialize a Json Object having hyphen or dash i.e - in its attribute name .. using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Sample Json -

```
{"error":
  {"message":"irp-return-error",
    "irp-err":{"ErrorCode":"1015","ErrorMessage":"Invalid Data for this user"}
  }
}
```

I tried setting the name using @SerializedName  Gson annotation

```
public class Error {
    @SerializedName("irp-err")
    private IrpErr irpErr;
    private String message;
```

but the call to the json object returns null.

```
Gson erngson = new Gson();
ErrResponse data = erngson.fromJson(response.readEntity(String.class), ErrResponse.class);
if(data.getError()!=null){
            IrpErr irperr = data.getError().getIrpErr(); //NPE
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are you trying to deserialize all of that JSON as `Error` or just the nested value `"error"`?

Comment: Yeah, this works fine for me. You'll need another (wrapper) class type to hold the `"error"` member.

Comment: @Savior My problem is similar to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536921/json-response-with-dash-in-the-key-name] where i am using Gson instead of Jackson library.

Comment: Like I said, your `fromJson` needs to pass a wrapper type that has a field called `error` of type `ErrResponse`.